# Returns Nothing [] from Google + API using Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-plus

Hi guys I hope all are doing well
I tried with GOOGLE + API using Python to get the Json format data.
you can view the code from below

```
       from apiclient import discovery
       API_KEY = '######'
       GPLUS = discovery.build('plus', 'v1', developerKey=API_KEY)
       #here i used V1 while using v2,v3,v4  i got the follwing errors
        items = 
       GPLUS.activities().search(query='python').execute().get('items', [])
       print(items)
       #returns nothing
       for data in items:
           post = ' '.join(data['title'].strip().split())
               if post:
                   print(TMPL % (data['actor']['displayName'],
                       data['published'], post))
                        #same problem executes nothing
```

responce

```
v2,v3,v4
HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting 
https://plus.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4&key=AIzaSyCgPkdet3KVbJ_Tzd5VgtYeFwWCQwpUVcE returned "Internal Server Error">
```

Answer (score 2):

> Legacy Google+ APIs have been shut down as of March 7, 2019.

Google plus was shut down in April 2019 at the same time or shortly before the Google+ api was also shut down.

This API no longer works this is why you are getting a 500 error.

[Google+ API Shutdown](https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown)

Comment: can we do with another python library or another API.Please share the code if it is possible

Comment: The library isnt going to help if the API you are trying to connect to does not exist anymore.   I dont know what you are trying to do but requesting data from a system that doesn't exist anymore ([Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/)) seams pointless.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do that you think another API would help?